# Combine two worksheets into a third

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have two worksheets I want to combine and display in a third. The first worksheet is a floating Employee List I update weekly. The second is the Hours worked itemized by each employee. The lists share the Employee_Id as a Unique Identifier.

So If Emp_ID = Emp_ID then display Emp_ID Location Terminal (both from the first sheet) and display Hours PTO Overtime and Total Hours (from the second sheet).

[Sample View of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qra0.png)
[image: Sample View of Data]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words.  Please show your data as is and what you want it to look like.

Comment: @ScottCraner I added an image sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Emp_ID is in A1 for both the first two sheets, copy A:F of Sheet2 into A1 of Sheet3. Once there add `Department` into G1, delete ColumnB and insert a new ColumnA. In G2 and copied down to suit:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!A:D,4,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula, it does not require copying and pasting between sheets:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet1!$A:$D,MATCH(C$1,Sheet1!$A$1:$D$1,0),FALSE),VLOOKUP($B2,Sheet2!$A:$H,MATCH(C$1,Sheet2!$A$1:$H$1,0),FALSE))
```

The headers need to be an exact match to the headers on the other two sheets.